# how to redirect with php?

Tags: php, html, header, action

I want my code once press submit to be redirected to another website.
I want this to be done through a PHP script so it can be expanded.
The problem is that when I test the code the PHP script is loaded in the browser with a blank page instead of redirecting it to the web I want.

I leave you my current code:

SIGN_IN.HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">

    <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="text-center">
    <div class="form-signin">
        <form action="post.php">
            <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Sign in"/>
            <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

POST.PHP

```
    <?php
    header ("Location: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/");exit;
    ?>
```

PD:As you can see, the page is an example website, I do not intend to carry out any cybercrime, just learn

Thanks

Comment: Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.[https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 1):

I think your file is Capital letter, right? It should be `post.php`, not `POST.php`.

Please check again.

I've tested your code with `post.php`. It works well.

Comment: the file is named post.php, in lowercase
When I try it instead of addressing it, I get a blank page, what could it be due to?